# How am I supposed to know the request to my bot originated from Teams?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, botframework

We are currently working on implementing a Teams chatbot but had some questions on authentication. How does the bot verify the request is coming from Teams and not just a cURL request?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand well your question. But if you want to check which channel is talking with your bot. You can always check the Activity.ChannelId.

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept events coming from Teams Channel using TeamsActivityHandler which is derived from ActivityHandler. It adds support for the Microsoft Teams specific events and interactions.

Hope this link also could help, https://dev.to/azure/beginners-guide-to-ms-teams-development-2-bots-590m